# update maven version for Cygwin

Tags: maven, cygwin

I downloaded and extracted the latest version of maven (apache-maven-3.8.4) to my Windows 10 machine and updated my **MAVEN_HOME** and **M2_HOME** environment variables accordingly to the new maven directory.

Running *env* from my Cygwin terminal now shows the updated maven location as expected. But *which mvn* shows my *old* maven dir location. Any idea why that would be and how I would fix it?

Comment: Check your PATH variable that you have multiple maven bin in the path.

Comment: Do not use MAVEN_HOME nor M2_HOME. Just put it into your PATH nothing else..So `which mvn` shows a different location?